# Making my Flash files into Android Apps?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I want to develop apps within Flash CS5, though I have no idea how to compile the Flash file for Android. Can anyone provide me with an overview of what I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This technology currently on Adobe Labs allows you to do just this: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashpro_extensionforair/